# Items do not respod in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigationview

I can't get my items to respond in my navigation drawer. The plan is to have a logout item that logout the user when clicked upon. The problem is that when i click on the item 'logout' it only closes the drawer and my code is ignored. Please help me, been on this for hours now!

XML code, activitymain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rebeckagerdtham.skane18.activities.menuActivity"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigationmenu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nav_menu">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/mCustomToolbar">
    </include>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML navigationmenu

```
<item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
    android:title="Logga ut"
    android:checked="false"

    />

<item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
    android:title="Inställningar"
    />
```

Java code

```
public class menuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Toolbar modifications
    Toolbar my_toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mCustomToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Meny");
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.log);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView nv = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_menu);
    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem){
            if(menuItem.getItemId()== R.id.nav_logout){
                Intent sendToLoginPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(sendToLoginPage);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigationmenu, menu);
    return true;

}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: The drawer `View` needs to be listed last within the `<DrawerLayout>`. Move your `<NavigationView>` to after the `<ConstraintLayout>`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!